# Animate the display of dynamically added html

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-animate

I couldn't find this solution anywhere.

The user makes selections and enters some values. When he clicks to add, I want the html that's added with jQuery to animate (or slide down) into view. How would the element height be retrieved in order to set the value?

This is the parent;

```
<div class="order-summary-wrap"></div>
```

This code works but it's jarring.

```
// build the summary boxes from the users inputs
function create_summary(){
    var summary_html = '';

    if( $('.cycle-01').hasClass('cycle-slide-active') ){
        summary_html = '<div class="toll-free-summary-contents remove-me"><p class="line-one"><span class="new-toll-free-number">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-2-container .number').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> in <span class="from-toll-free-country">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-1-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> will ring to <span class="forward-to-number">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-3-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> in <span class="to-toll-free-country">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-4-container #ForwardNumberTo').attr("value") + '</span></p><p class="line-two"><span class="toll-free-cost">' + $('.billing-options-hidden').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> (FIRST MONTH FREE) with each minute used costing  <span class="toll-free-per-minute-cost">' + $('.per-minute').text() + '</span></p><div class="remove"><a class="remove-link" href="#">Remove</a><a class="view-link" href="#">View Sample Bill</a></div></div>';
    } else {
        summary_html = '<div class="local-summary-contents remove-me"><p class="line-one"><span class="country-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-1-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="state-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-2-container .state').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="city-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-3-container .city').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="new-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-4-container .local').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span></p><p class="line-two"><span class="toll-free-cost">' + $('.billing-options-hidden').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> (FIRST MONTH FREE) with each minute used costing  <span class="toll-free-per-minute-cost">' + $('.per-minute').text() + '</span></p><div class="remove"><a class="remove-link" href="#">Remove</a><a class="view-link" href="#">View Sample Bill</a></div></div>';
    }

    $('.order-summary-wrap').append(summary_html);
    $('.add-more-numbers').removeClass('hidden');
}

// click event to dynamically add the summary boxes to the DOM
$('.first-step, .add-number').click(function(e){
    create_summary();
});
```

Also, when the "remove" link is clicked, I'd like for the element to animate as it's removed from the DOM.

```
// lets the user remove the number from the DOM
$('.order-summary-wrap').on('click', '.remove-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the new summary_html that you want to slide down, you could do it like this.  Hide the DOM element before appending it, then use `.slideDown()` to make it visible after appending it.

Here's a working demo (with simpler code to illustrate): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gHcZJ/

And, here's your code with that implemented:

```
// build the summary boxes from the users inputs
function create_summary(){
    var summary_html = '';

    if( $('.cycle-01').hasClass('cycle-slide-active') ){
        summary_html = $('<div class="toll-free-summary-contents remove-me"><p class="line-one"><span class="new-toll-free-number">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-2-container .number').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> in <span class="from-toll-free-country">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-1-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> will ring to <span class="forward-to-number">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-3-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> in <span class="to-toll-free-country">' + $('.cycle-01 .step-4-container #ForwardNumberTo').attr("value") + '</span></p><p class="line-two"><span class="toll-free-cost">' + $('.billing-options-hidden').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> (FIRST MONTH FREE) with each minute used costing  <span class="toll-free-per-minute-cost">' + $('.per-minute').text() + '</span></p><div class="remove"><a class="remove-link" href="#">Remove</a><a class="view-link" href="#">View Sample Bill</a></div></div>');
    } else {
        summary_html = $('<div class="local-summary-contents remove-me"><p class="line-one"><span class="country-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-1-container .country').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="state-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-2-container .state').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="city-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-3-container .city').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span>  <span class="new-local-number">' + $('.cycle-02 .step-4-container .local').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span></p><p class="line-two"><span class="toll-free-cost">' + $('.billing-options-hidden').find("option:selected").attr("value") + '</span> (FIRST MONTH FREE) with each minute used costing  <span class="toll-free-per-minute-cost">' + $('.per-minute').text() + '</span></p><div class="remove"><a class="remove-link" href="#">Remove</a><a class="view-link" href="#">View Sample Bill</a></div></div>');
    }
    summary_html.hide();
    $('.order-summary-wrap').append(summary_html);
    summary_html.slideDown();
}

// click event to dynamically add the summary boxes to the DOM
$('.first-step, .add-number').click(function(e){
    create_summary();
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Very clean and a nice approach. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00 beat me to it. You can do the same for removing the number from the DOM.

```
$('.order-summary-wrap').on('click', '.remove-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp().remove();
});
```

Comment: Not sure this will actually show the animation.  I think the `.remove()` will run immediately before the animation.  Probably have to do the `.remove()` in the animation completion function.

Comment: Ah yeah. sorry, wrote that quick on a train.  You're correct, the .remove() will need to be run in the callback of slideUp().

Comment: Thanks for the help. @A Placing '.remove' in the callback of '.slideUp' worked perfectly.